# How to run an scheduled Agent on a local database in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, agent

Lotus 8.5.3

What I need to do is launch an external process in response to an incoming email that matches certain criteria.

Rules cannot do this. Fair enough, looks like the Agent can.

Ok, so setup a LotusScript with an Agent to do what I need, test it with Run--> perfect

Now to get it to run from an email.  Simple, right?

Ok, several hours of google fu later and we have some possible problems.

First, discover it must be a local agent in order to have access to the Client files to launch a process.  Test that everything else works by running a simple Move action (without requiring local access).  This works, so its an access problem.

Set it up as a local agent --> it never gets called.

Next discover that a local agent cannot act in response to incoming email.  Sure, lets setup a 5 minutes schedule.  No go.

Next, ensure that "Enable Scheduled Local Agents" in the properties and restart.  No go.  The Agent simply is not called,

Next, learn that in order for a Local Agent to run, it must be located within a local database.

And... that's where I've stalled.  No amount of google seems able to answer this for me.  What is a local database?  I tried going to my Archive folder, then clicking "Create->Agent" to create an agent there (its local, right?)  But this did not work either.

So, how can I create a local database which receive emails, and from which I can create an Agent which acts upon the local file system?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the designer client installed?

Comment: Could you clarify which external process you mean? Do you want it to run when the user opens the email or when the mail is received?

Are you sure you want an agent that does something to the local file server without user interaction when a mail message is received? Sounds like a recipe for virus-like activity.

You could also simply add the code to a button in the mail template for all users mail files, for them to click when the proper criteria are met.

Comment: Yes I have Designer Client installed, and am able to create and run Agents manually- just not on the schedule.

Comment: @David - I need it to run when a mail message is received.  No concerns about virus, this is only for my own PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local database is a database that resides on user's computer. In this case it would be a *replica* of the server database.

The solution is to create a replica (*File -> Replication -> New Replica...*) on user's computer and make it replicate with server on desired interval. If there are a lot of users this might be a bigger thing to arrange.

Comment: To add to this, the agent doesn't have to be in the same database. So you can create a blank database in "Local" and then open it in designer and create your agent there.

Comment: Excellent, I was unaware of this.  I am setting up a new replica now and will try to run the agent from there.

Comment: Yes -- problem solved!  I could not find this information anywhere.  It still don't see exactly how to choose which Replica the agent is in-- "View Agents" or "Create Agent" shows up the same no matter which Inbox I am in.  However, as soon as I created the Replica all of the Agents I had created just started working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the agent to run in the user's mail file. If that is the case and you have a Domino server, set it to run on the server, in the user's mail file. The mail is alkso received in the server replica of the user's mail file.